# How to add items to a List<T> and display them in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm developing a simple bank application that's supposed to (in some way) display the customers of the bank. I chose a listbox to display the items but let me know if there's an easier way.

The problem I'm having is that the ListBox is't displaying anything and I think that the problem is that the Customers that I'm trying to add isn't added in the first place.

Soo, first off, I have this in my Customer class where the attributes for every customer are set:

```
public class Customer
{
    string CustomerName;
    long IDNumber;
    List<SavingsAccount> CustomerAccounts;

    public Customer()
    {
    }

    public Customer(string _customerName, long _iDNumber, List<SavingsAccount> _customerAccounts)
    {
        this.customerName = _customerName;
        this.iDNumber = _iDNumber;
        CustomerAccounts = new List<SavingsAccount>();
    }

    public string customerName
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerName;
        }
        set
        {                
            CustomerName = value;
        }
    }

    public long iDNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return IDNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            IDNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public List<SavingsAccount> customerAccounts
    {
        get
        {
            return CustomerAccounts;
        }
        set
        {
            CustomerAccounts = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the application the user can navigate to an "Add customer page" where they can type in a name and personal ID in two separate textBoxes. A button witch "saves" the customer triggers this event:

```
private void addCustomer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        long pnr = Convert.ToInt64(idTextBox.Text);

        bankLogic.AddCustomer(nameTextBox.Text, pnr).ToString();
```

The AddCustomer method looks like this:

```
public bool AddCustomer(string name, long idNumber)
    {
        foreach (Customer c in customers)
        {
            if (c.iDNumber != idNumber)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.customerName = name;
        customer.iDNumber = idNumber;
        customer.customerAccounts = null;

        customers.Add(new Customer(customer.customerName, customer.iDNumber, customer.customerAccounts));

        return true;
    }
```

In another part of the application witch the user can navigate to, there's a ListBox and a button. The button triggers an event that's supposed to fill the ListBox with the customers. In the xaml.cs file the event lookes like this:

```
private void FillButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Customer> myCustomers = bankLogic.GetCustomers();
        foreach (Customer c in myCustomers)
        {
            customerList.Items.Add(c.customerName);
        }
    }
```

The `bankLogic.GetCustomers();` just returns the list with the customers:

```
public List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return customers;
    }
```

So the question is: Is the names and IDNumbers added to the List at all? Or why isn't they displayed in the ListBox?

Thanks for all answers! This is my first time, sorry for the long post :)

Comment: First of all,your `AddCustomer` method has something wrong. Why do you create a new instance of `Customer`,fill all the properties, and then don't do anything with it?

Comment: And second, learn to debug. Put a breakpoint for example in your `GetCustomers` method and see if `customers`has any data.

Comment: it seem a bit over complicating things to me, is there any particular reason you need custom properties? for a listbox to show a list you might need to set the DataTemplate in XAML, can you show the XAML of your listbox, and another thing a "List" does not contain the InotifyPropertyChanged interface, an ObservableCollection does contain that and this may explain why your listbox isn't being updated in real time.

Comment: @Pikoh What should I do with the new Customer instance to add it to my List?

Comment: Instead of `customers.Add(new Customer(customer.customerName, customer.iDNumber, customer.customerAccounts));` just `customers.Add(customer)`. But this was just something that got my eye, I don't think that's the reason of your problem.

Comment: @Pikoh Ok. @Dark Templar This is not the full application. And the reason for having custom properties is that I've been told to do so pretty much :/ This is the XAML for the ListBox: `<ListBox x:Name="customerList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="90" Margin="32,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="227"/>`

Comment: @Exibe basically the only reason to use custom properties is when a standard property(string, int and such) are not enough, if you can avoid them do it, only use them if you must, looking at your class from what I understand basically you only need 3 objects a string and an int and a list, Is it possible to use your class as a viewmodel for a datatemplate on your listbox?

Comment: @Dark Templar Okey, thanks :) I'm not sure, I'm not familiar with the viewmodel concept so probably not in my case.